If statement isn't showing console.log when condition passed and continue work as unexpected
So there's a simple code with vanilla JavaScript.
const button = document.getElementById('btn');
const input = document.getElementById('amount');

let list = [];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let num = +input.value;

    if (typeof num === 'number') {
        list.push(num);
        console.log(list);
    }

    else {
         console.log('Error. Try again and type in a number');
    }
})

Why the console.log statement isn't showing up in the console but instead it pushes NaN value to the list?
I tried to use else if instead of just else and passed the following condition: typeof num !== 'number'

You have two separate issues, the console message not showing up is separate from the NaN issue. typeof NaN is "number" so you can't use typeof to check if converting to number succeeded. You need to use isNaN instead.

I cannot reproduce this. Please make sure you provide the code to really reproduce the problem you describe.

= +input.value will ALWAYS convert the value to a number. If its not a valid number, the result will be "NaN" (not a number) but the type will still be number. As stated before, you have to check with "isNaN"

thanks for answers, guys, the problem is solved!

The comments have basically already answered it, but I'll try my best to sum it up and explain it to you.
In JavaScript, the plus operator before a string, let num = +input.value; in your case, will always convert the given string into a number, even if it isn't valid. To handle this, JavaScript has NaN, which stands for Not a Number, which funnily enough, is a number. So to actually check whether your input is a number, you have to use the isNaN function:
const button = document.getElementById('btn');
const input = document.getElementById('amount');

let list = [];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let num = +input.value;

    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        list.push(num);
        console.log(list);
    } else {
         console.log('Error. Try again and type in a number');
    }
})


Thank you really much, this solved my confusion over the unexpected challenge:)
